# Android org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 1526

Tags: android, json

I am having the following problem and I am stuck in it from a while and don't know what is the problem

I am getting the error

org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 1526, as following the print of the response string

[image]

and as following my method

```
public void getItemType(final Context context,final ItemTypeRequestUIListener uiListener) {

    if (PhoneUtils.isNetworkAvailable(context) == true) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {

                    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(AppConstants.URL_DO_LIST_LOOKUP);
                    request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                    request.setEntity(new StringEntity(AppConstants.URL_DO_LIST_LOOKUP_ITEM_JSON_PARAM_FORMAT));

                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    if (entity.getContentLength() != 0) {

                        Reader objectReader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
                        char[] buffer = new char[(int) response.getEntity().getContentLength()];
                        objectReader.read(buffer);
                        objectReader.close();
                        String str = new String(buffer);
                        str = str.replace("?", "");
                        Log.i("AMIRA", "TYPES RESPONSE : " + str);
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(str);
                        uiListener.onRequestCompleted(ItemTypeResponse.parseJSONObject(jsonResponse),null);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    uiListener.onRequestCompleted(null,AppError.GENERAL_ERROR);
                }
                return null;
            };
        }.execute();
    } else {
        uiListener.onRequestCompleted(null, AppError.NO_INTERNET);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the problem here ?

Comment: Those Arabic characters perhaps?

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak So what should I do to solve this problem ??

Comment: Try finding something about encoding/decoding those characters to unicode

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that you are using the wrong character encoding to read the stream.

A line of code like this:

`Reader objectReader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());`

is always dangerous because you are not explicitly specifying what character set to use.

You can try this:

`Reader objectReader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");`

if you know your server is sending UTF-8 content.

The best way to handle this is to read the `Content-Type` header in the response which could be something like:

`Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8`

Parse the string after "charset=" and pass that as the character set name.

In effect you are specifying the character set that the server said it is using.

But be careful: The charset parameter is optional and may not be present.

As an extreme fallback, you could catch the `JSONException` and retry the parse with a different encoding.  You would have to buffer the response somewhere so that you could re-read it.

Comment: I have tried it but it still not working, sometimes it work and sometimes it through exception.